# What takes precedence: favourite tag or ignored tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

What happens in my Questions feed if a question appears that has tags in my Favourite Tags list and my Ignored tags list? Which one will supersede the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This Happens:

[image: Fave + Ignore]

I have [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) ignored and [professional-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professional-gaming) as a favorite for the purposes of this example. As you can see, the question "**What kind of Companies sponsor pro teams?**" is faded out, but also has the blue hilight of a 'favorite' tagged question.

If you set the preference to hide ignored tags to on, than the question will be hidden, regardless of whether it also has a Favorite Tag associated with it.

Answer (score -2):

Since the parser simply acts to highlight questions that are in your Favorites tag and removes questions in your Ignored tags list, I have to assume that logically the Ignored list will take precedence. Pretty easy to test, though?

Comment: Ignored questions aren't actually removed by default, but if you enable that option, yes, that's what happens.